# Typescript not compiling AngularFire Get "asArray" code

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angularfire, angular

Typescript not compiling AngularFire Get "asArray" code.

The outcome I want is for the typescript to compile without the AngularFire signature error in the console.

Just to clarify, my code works but the typescript compiler contains 1 error.

Seems that AngularFire doesnt work well with the typescript compiler.

**Here is my code (I've put a comment where the issue is):**

```
   import {Component, View, bootstrap, bind, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
   import {Router, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
   import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
   import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

   import {Todo} from './components/todo/todo';
   import {AuthService} from './authService';
   import {EnvironmentService} from './environmentService';

   import {AngularFire, FirebaseArray} from '../firebase/angularfire';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app'
   })

   @View({
       template: `
           <div class="container">
               <nav>
                   <ul>                 
                       <li><a (click)="getAllProfiles()">Get all profile</a></li>       
                   </ul>
               </nav>
               <router-outlet></router-outlet>
           </div>
       `,
       directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
   })

   @RouteConfig([
       { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
       { path: '/home', component: Todo, as: 'Home' }
   ])

   @Injectable()
   export class AppComponent {
       listOfProfiles:FirebaseArray;
       data: AngularFire;

       constructor(){
       }

       //Error Here - This works but has typescript signature error:    
       public getAllProfiles(){
           this.data = new AngularFire(new        Firebase('https://markng2.firebaseio.com/profiles'));
           this.listOfProfiles = this.data.asArray();       

           console.log(this.listOfProfiles.list);
       }
   }

   bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}), HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthService, EnvironmentService]);
```

**Here is a screen shot of the typescript compiler error (Its the last message):**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this AngularFire compatible with angular2? take a look on this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/kEk9qQVYP34 could be old.

Comment: Do you know one that is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript compiler error - supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732897/typescript-compiler-error-supplied-parameters-do-not-match-any-signature-of-ca)